# Webservice client shows errors on weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 (12cR2) - soapfault

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I am posting a web service request using a client and see

> HTTP 500 internal error. The server logs shows
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Fault code is not valid for SOAP 1.2.

Client logs -

> weblogic.wsee.WseeCoreMessages errorLogException
>       SEVERE: Error while invoking endpoint http://10.4.3.6:8001/abc/MyGatewayPort?WSDL from client; ServiceName:
>   {urn:MyGateWay}MyGateway ; PortName: {urn:MyGateWay}MyGatewayPort ;
>   Client side features:
>   [weblogic.jws.jaxws.client.ClientIdentityFeature]; Client side
>   policies: 
>       com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 500: Internal Server Error
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:288)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:232)
>               at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.transport.http.client.WLSHttpTransportPipe.process(WLSHttpTransportPipe.java:30)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:139)
>               at ---
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
>               at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
>               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.myWebMethod(Unknown Source)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>               at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:147)
>               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.myWebMethod(Unknown Source)
>               at com.myexperiement.webservices.sample.webservice.myWebMethod(MyGatewayService.java:175)
>               at mypackage.myPortClient.main(MyPortClient.java:94)

===========================================================
The server logs shows -

> <10.4.3.6>  <[STANDBY]
>   ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default
>   (self-tuning)'> <> <>
>   <77e36124-9d15-4502-afd5-3e59a9a4b633-00002493> <1533010823326>
>   <[severity-value: 32] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name:
>   DOMAIN] >   MACHINE = 10.4.3.6 MSGID = BEA-101017 DATE = Jul
>   30, 2018, 9:20:23,313 PM PDT SUBSYSTEM = HTTP CONTEXTID =
>   77e36124-9d15-4502-afd5-3e59a9a4b633-00002492 TXID =  SEVERITY = Error
>   THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '31' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
>       WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset
>       WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 30000

Could you please help to understand this issue and what could be missing in webservice client to post request?

Thanks